# If can in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan

In my application I have following code:

```
@object.start if can? :start, @object
```

I searched for it and found that app is using cancan gem, but as a beginner I am not getting what this code does exactly. There is no such a function defined with "`start`" name.

I am totally stuck on this as I am not getting from where to start and what to search.

Comment: What is `@object` object of?

Comment: You might want to read the [documentation of the cancan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Comment: Paste your model code here

Comment: `can :start, Pipeline, user_id: user.id`  this is what written in ability.rb

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how the application is working, but the `can?` definitely comes from the [cancan gem](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

You can specify the permissions in the `app/models/ability.rb` file.

It simply reads the ability file to determine if a user can perform some action or not. These actions correspond directly to the actions you have defined in the controller class.

Cancan has a great wiki at its github repositiory. Also, the screencast by ryan is an excellent place to start off with.

You can also see the screencast [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).